# Redirect и Routing в React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redirect, react-router

У пытаюсь написать веб чат. Пока-что у меня 2 компонента, `main` компонент и `signup` комопонент. Мне надо что б `signup` компонент отображался первым если человек впервые заходит на сайт. Как в мессенджерах, сперва должен зарегистрироваться, у тебя открываеться `signup` страница и только после регистрации открываеться `main` компонент. Также я использую `React Router`

**Мой код в** `App.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Signup from './components/signup/signup';
import Main from './components/main/main';

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
       <Route path='/' element={<Main />} />
       <Route path='signup' element={<Signup />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что Route вам здесь вообще нужен? Если вам надо отображать компоненты по условию, то добавьте условие в рендер и задача будет успешно решена

Comment: Если впервые означает, что он не зареган, то в компоненте `Main` вам надо просто посмотреть в `localStorage` и посмотреть есть ли данные о юзере? Если есть значит он зареган и вы его пускаете, если нет, то перекидываете на `Signup` и после успешной регистрации записываете в `localStorage` данные пользователя. Главное не храните пароль там в открытом виде :)

Comment: @EzioMercer понял, буду разбираться. То есть Routing тут не нужен? Как юзера перекинуть в `Signup`?

Comment: Роутинг нужен, как без этого вы его перекинете с главной страницы на регистрацию? "Как перекинуть" - это читайте документацию. Давно уже не работал с React, но должно быть что-то типа `navigate` если не ошибаюсь

Comment: @EzioMercer, понял, спасибо, буду разбираться

Comment: В компоненте App делаете проверку и помещаете значение в переменную состояния, допустим **isLogin**, а в рендере `{isLogin ? <Main /> : <Signup  />}` И роутинг тут не нужен, если он затевается ради проверки и выводу 2-х компонентов

Answer (score 0):

> Как в мессенджерах, сперва должен зарегистрироваться, у тебя открываеться signup страница и только после регистрации открываеться main компонент.

Как иллюстрацию, могу предложить вот такую конструкцию редиректа.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
 
function App() {
    
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Main />} />
                <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

//
function Signup() {
    return <p>Signup</p>
}

//
function Main() {
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    // Эта переменная будет отвечать за авторизован или нет (пока не авторизован)
    const ok = false
    React.useEffect(_ => {
        if (!ok) navigate('/signup')
    }, [ok])
        
    return <p>Main</p>
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />);
```

Comment: Не вставляйте запускаемый код, если он не запускаем

Comment: @EzioMercer, как скажешь...

Answer (score 0):

Для вывода одного из двух компонентов, я бы не стал использовать route, а воспользовался бы условным рендерингом

```
function App() {
  function checkAuth() {
    // Проверяем, авторизрован ли пользователь
    return result; // true / false
  }
  return (
    <>
      {checkAuth() ? <Main /> : <Signup />}
    </>
  );
}
```